# Array after link_to - rails file upload model

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, template-engine, link-to

I upload documents and then on my admin home page I display all the documents like so:

```
<% @document.each do |document|%> 
     <p><%= link_to document.name, document.contract_url.to_s%></p>
<%end%>
```

In my user's home page I render the documents that belong to specific users like so:

```
<%= current_user.documents.each do |document|%>
    <p><%= link_to document.name, document.contract_url.to_s%></p>
<%end%>
```

But in the user's home page I get this array after my link.

```
Document Name (link)
[#<Document id: 2, name: "Document Name", user_id: 2, contract: "contract_name.pdf", created_at: "2012-10-03 13:12:40", updated_at: "2012-10-03 13:35:35">]
```

I do not get this array in my admin panel. I just get the "Document Name" link. 
Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[#<Document id: 2, name: "Document Name", user_id: 2, contract: "contract_name.pdf", created_at: "2012-10-03 13:12:40", updated_at: "2012-10-03 13:35:35">]
```

is not a hash, it's an Array. It's an Array with a single class instance of your `Document` model.

```
#<Document id: 2, name: "Document Name", user_id: 2, contract: "contract_name.pdf", created_at: "2012-10-03 13:12:40", updated_at: "2012-10-03 13:35:35">
```

This is the return value *(String representation of a model)* of the following *(try it in `rails console` to see)*

```
Document.find(2).to_s
```

In your code you have

```
<%= current_user.documents.each do |document|%>
```

You are **printing** the `current_user.documents` collection. This is the same as you doing

```
puts current_user.documents
```

in `rails console`. Get rid of the `=`.

```
<% current_user.documents.each do |document|%>
```